# Python Darknet script for object detection is not detecting anything in the input images but when ran through command line it gives proper detection

Tags: python, opencv, yolo, darknet

I have trained a yolo v3 network by using my own data set to detect two classes.
Repository used for the training is https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/

After training I used below command to get the output -
darknet.exe detector demo cfg/labelled_data.data cfg/custom_test.cfg backup/custom_train_8000.weights test_folder/test_1.mp4

If I used the above command gets expected output with 80% of accuracy.
But when i try to run the detection using the python scripts provided in the repository i am not able to get any detection.
Script in the repo for images -
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/darknet_images.py

Script in the repo for video -
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/darknet_video.py

I have a GPU machine which i have used for development.
I have written a opencv script to get the detection output on realtime feed. The script is working as expected but the problem is that it is not able to utilize the GPU hence resulting in very slow detection.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you run the python script for image?

Comment: By calling darknet_images.py file and passed the required cfg, data and weight file paths as arguments